# Random string from a set of available strings in Excel but exclude specific Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010.  I'm using an INDEX and RANDBETWEEN function to lookup a list of available strings and return one of them.  However, I have a specific value, D3, (in this instance but will change with each row D4, D5 etc) that I need to exclude from the random results - what is the best way to achieve this?  This is my current formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$D,MATCH($B3&"|"&LEFT($C3,SEARCH("-",$C3))&L3,$A:$A,0)+RANDBETWEEN(0,S3-1),4),"")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please remove those code parts not relevant to your issue and reduce everything to the problem you actually need to solve. The IFERROR(), MATCH(), LEFT() and SEARCH() calls are not related to your issue but make it hard to understand your code.
To simplify, I assume:

- range D1:D199 is filled with (potentially duplicate) strings
- each cell in column E1:E199 is supposed to draw a random string from the whole of D1:D199, except those that are identical to the cell on its left (in D)

Copy + paste the following code into E1, then enter it as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=INDEX(D:D,LARGE(IF((D1:D200<>"")*(D1:D200<>D1),ROW(D1:D200),-1),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM((D1:D200<>"")*(D1:D200<>D1)))))
```

You can then copy cell E1 to E2:E199

Updated code with Dirk Reichel's suggestions.

Comment: if I put in F2: `=COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E2)` and copy down, it tells me that there are doubles...

Comment: to get the exact row at which the number already occured the first time, just `=IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E27,E28),MATCH(E28,E:E,0),"")` in E2 and copy down will do.

Comment: @DirkReichel - as I understand it the author does not mind duplicates within column E, but he wants to avoid that horizontally adjacent cells in D and E get the same value

Comment: you are "completely" right... this way my answer is also "completely" wrong :P

Comment: Also, if dealing with empty strings, then `{=INDEX(D:D,LARGE(IF((D1:D200<>"")*(D1:D200<>D1),ROW(D1:D200)),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM(IF((D1:D200<>"")*(D1:D200<>D1),1)))))}` will also exclude them ;)

Comment: I have a feeling we keep solving something he doesn't care that much about anymore ;). Anyways, nice addition!

Comment: I'm still here.  And still cannot solve it.  @UlliSchmid you are right - I want to avoid the string in the horizontal cell in D1

Comment: @Michael open a new excel sheet and try to follow the steps in the answer above. Please provide information if you want us to help you.

Comment: I think I might just start this from scratch, but thank you for your contributions.